# Добавить эмоджи на изображение

Tags: node.js, обработка-изображений, emoji

Я делаю бота, который создаёт цитаты вставляя текст на определённый фон. Но если текст содержит эмоджи, то они просто не отображаются на выходе. Пробовал использовать ultimate-text-to-image, но в таком случае они отображаются в чёрно-белом формате, а надо чтобы они были цветными, как это можно осуществить?

Пример цитaты:

[image: Пример как работает сейчас]

Comment: Какими библиотеками пользуетесь? Можете предоставить код, содержащий создание изображения?

Comment: const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
const { UltimateTextToImage, registerFont } = require("ultimate-text-to-image");
 
let text_to_image = await new UltimateTextToImage(
  text_quote, 
  {
   width: TEXT_FRAME_WIDTH, 
   fontColor: "#FFFFFF", 
   fontFamily: "Arial, Sans",
   fontSize: size_text,
   align: 'center'
  }
 )
text_to_image.render().toFile(`text.png`);

И потом через gm вставляю получившиеся изображение вместе с другими частями цитаты на фон